# Mac App To Make External HDD Bootable

Tags: install, leopard, powerpc, macos

Instead of using DiskMaker, is there another app to make Mac OS X 10.4 or 10.5 (ppc) bootable without creating a bootable usb? I want to copy all the contents of the Mac OS X Install DVD straight to the external HDD and make it bootable when I put it into another machine.

Comment: Do you have the universal install DVDs or machine-specific (grey color) DVD installer discs which came with a Mac for macOS installation?

Comment: I have Mac Os X Install Dvd image

Comment: You have a physical DVD disc, or just an disk image of one?

Comment: An image of one, it’s on my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the Apple supported "createinstallmedia" command does not work with macOS versions prior to Mavericks.

However it is possible to restore the MacOS installer disk image (inside the installer .app package) to a USB thumb drive.

1. Using Disk utility format the USB drive with Mac OS Journaled format
2. Right-Click on the .app package for the version of MacOS that you want to create a bootable installer from and select Show Package Contents from the pop-up menu that appears.
3. Copy the .dmg file therein to your desktop. I forget what it is called but is will be several GB in size and the only one there.
4. Select the recently formatted USB key on the left side of Disk utility and find the "Restore" command. It may be in the Edit menu (Mojave) or an icon on the Disk Utility title bar.
5. Select the .dmg image file you copied to the desktop to restore from and click the restore button.

That will image the USB key using the installer .dmg file as the source. It will take 10 minutes or so but when you are done you will have a bootable USB key to install that version of macOS from.

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to do is install 10.4 tiger (ppc) straight to an external hdd using my Macbook pro (intel), like an App that will copy the contents of my Mac Os X Install Dvd to an external drive, then make it boot.

Comment: Please make changes to your original question that clarifies. Note that the macOS installer will likely not even run to allow you to do that as you are, essentially, installing an unsupported OS on that Mac. You will have to install that version of macOS **ON** a mac that supports that version. Trying to work around that restriction is an exercise in frustration.